# How do i do this simple SQL SELECT statement?

Tags: sql, select, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm having trouble with what I think should be the simplest of SQL statements, however it is not working for me...

I have 4 tables: S, P, J and SPJ where SPJ is basically a table linking all the ID's together.

Now, the statement required is: "Get supplier numbers for suppliers who supply part P2 and part P4."

`SELECT SNO FROM SPJ WHERE PNO = 'P2' AND PNO = 'P4'`
- returns no results (which is wrong)

`SELECT SNO FROM SPJ WHERE PNO = 'P2' UNION SELECT SNO FROM SPJ WHERE PNO = 'P4'`
- returns the result, plus an extra which only supplies one of the two...

I've tried all manner of statements but can't figure it out, I know it's got to be simple, but I just can't see it...

Anybody got any ideas?

Cheers

Comment: Would help us if you provide some sample data and expected results, and the results that are returned when you execute the above statements @Chris

Comment: Don't use AND as this would result in incorrect boolean logic.  Change the AND to an OR.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will get you suppliers who provide *both* parts, as opposed to those who supply either/or.

```
select sno
    from spj
    where pno in ('P2','P4')
    group by sno
    having count(distinct pno) = 2
```

Answer (score 2):

Or as an alternative to @Sathya

```
SELECT SNO 
FROM SPJ 
WHERE PNO = 'P2'
OR PNO = 'P4'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SNO FROM SPJ WHERE PNO in ('P2','P4')
```

Comment: ...to clarify, OP used `AND`. A single record cannot have both `'P2'` and `'P4'` in `PNO` at the same time. The operator in the original query should have been `OR`.

Comment: as with the second statement, this returns a result that only supplies the one...

Comment: @Chris Edwards: That is because this query does not exclude suppliers that supply things besides P2 and P4. This requirement will add a slight twist of complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Better to use OR

```
SELECT SNO FROM SPJ WHERE PNO = 'P2' OR PNO= 'P4'
```

Comment: this will return results that supplier either or, and i want only suppliers who do both...

Answer (score 0):

"SELECT SNO FROM SPJ WHERE PNO = 'P2' AND PNO = 'P4'"

obviously PNO can't be both P2 and p4 at the same time.
it's difficult to answer your question without a knowing the db scheme, you should give a description of your tables.